# How to show the count of all items in cross joined table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has all Items in the inventory, table called **CI**

**CI** has 2 columns (`ProdID` and `Price`), and it looks like this

```
ProdID Price
-------------
A8373  700
G8745  900
J7363  300
K7222  800
Y6311  350
```

I have another table for documents called `Docs` with columns `DocID`, `CustID` and `InvoiceID`.

```
DocID, CustID, InvoiceID
------------------------
1      1001    751
2      1001    752
3      1001    753
4      1002    831
5      1002    832
6      1003    901
7      1003    902
```

Another table for purchases called `Purchase` with `DocID`, `ProdID`, `ProdSize`.

In the same invoice, `ProdID` can be repeated as it can be in different sizes

```
DocID, ProdID, ProdSize
------------------------
1      A8373   41
1      A8373   42
1      A8373   43
1      G8745   35
1      G8745   36
2      A8373   44
2      A8373   45
```

Now I want to get the quantity of of products for all customer and invoice, but for highest priced products

So it should be like this

```
CustID, InvoiceID, ProdID, Quantity
-----------------------------------
1001    751        A8373   3
1001    751        G8745   2
1001    751        K7222   0
1001    752        A8373   2
1001    752        G8745   0
1001    752        K7222   0
```

and to show 0 for the products that do not exist in that invoice

I wrote this query, but it is extremely slow. I wonder if there is an easier fast way to get this results

```
DECLARE @Features AS TABLE 
                     (
                         CustID varchar(100), 
                         InvoiceID varchar(100) 
                             INDEX IX3 CLUSTERED(CustID, InvoiceID), 
                         ProdID varchar(100), 
                         Quantity bigint
                     )
        
INSERT INTO @Features (CustID, InvoiceID, ProdID, Quantity)
    SELECT 
        R.CustID, R.InvoiceID, T.ProdID, COUNT(*) AS Quantity
    FROM 
        Docs R 
    CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM CIs ORDER BY Price DESC) C
    INNER JOIN 
        Purchase T ON T.DocID = R.DocID
    GROUP BY 
        R.CustID, R.InvoiceID, T.ProdID

SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM @Features 
ORDER BY CustID, InvoiceID, ProdID

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Features

UPDATE F 
SET Quantity = Cnt
FROM @Features F 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT R.CustID, R.InvoiceID, COUNT(*) Cnt
     FROM Purchase T 
     INNER JOIN Docs R ON T.DocID = R.DocID
     GROUP BY R.CustID, R.InvoiceID ) X ON F.CustID = X.CustID 
                                        AND F.InvoiceID = X.InvoiceID

SELECT * FROM @Features
```

Comment: Can you explain the expected results. In the example you got -> (1001,751,G8745,0) and (1001,751,K7222,0) how is this part of the expected results

Comment: You said `I want to get the quantity of of products for all customer and invoice, but for highest priced products`. So the result should be only for `G8745` since it is the highest price ?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph the highest 1000 prodcuts ( so if the invoice does not have this product it will show 0 in the quantity)

Comment: @Squirrel it is for the highest 1000 products not just the hightest product)

Comment: You got (1001    751        G8745   2) and (1001    751        G8745   0) in your expected results, how do you explain those

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph that is a minstake it is suppose to be 752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way to do this. I filter out the 1000 products first and then perform the join as follows..

Also there isn't a need for update query, all could be obtained in the SQL itself.

Filter early join late

```
with top_product
  as (select prodid,price, rownumber() over(order by price desc) as rnk
         from ci
      )
     ,invoice_product
     as(select d.docid,d.custid,d.invoiceid,p.prodid
          from top_product
          join docs d
            on 1=1
           and rnk<=1000
       ) 
   select a.CustID, a.InvoiceID, a.ProdID,count(b.prodid) as qty
     from invoice_product a
left join purchase b
       on a.DocID=b.docid
      and a.ProdID=b.prodid
 group by a.CustID, a.InvoiceID, a.ProdID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK` as follows:

```
select CustID, InvoiceID, ProdID, sum(qty) as qty 
  from (select d.CustID, d.InvoiceID, ci.ProdID, p.prodid as qty,
               dense_rank() over (order by ci.price desc) as rn
          from ci cross join docs d 
          left join purchase p on d.docid = p.docid and ci.prodid = p.prodid) t
  where rn <= 1000
group by CustID, InvoiceID, ProdID
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following SQL Select statement where I used Common Table Expression [SQL CTEs](https://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

```
with topproducts as (
    select top 3 ProdID from CI order by Price desc
), sales as (
    select
        CustID,
        InvoiceID,
        ProdId,
        count(ProdId) as cnt
    from (
        select 
            d.CustID, 
            d.InvoiceID,
            p.ProdId
        from Docs d
        inner join Purchase p
            on p.DocID = d.DocID
        where p.ProdId in (select ProdId from topproducts)
    ) t1
    group by 
        CustID,
        InvoiceID,
        ProdId
)
select
    t.*, isnull(ss.cnt,0) as Qty
from (
select 
    distinct s.CustID, s.InvoiceID, p.ProdId
from sales s, topproducts p
) t
left join sales ss on ss.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID and ss.ProdId = t.ProdId
```

[image]